# Any good frameworks for onboarding users in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good framework / open source code for onboarding users.  Basically something which can display help screen when users first download and use your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you found something, but for others out there who might still be searching, take a look at this one:

https://github.com/workshirt/WSCoachMarksView

Comment: I actually ended up adapting a framework called 'CMPopTipView' https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView.  You can check out what I ended up doing in my app called Fridge Pal.  I like the lok of WSCoach but I'd worry that it'd be hard to deal with different screen sized / positions if you have to hardcode the element rects.

Comment: I was worried about the same thing, but then I simply used the 'frame' property of whichever view I wanted to focus on, and that worked out great!

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why you need a framework; there's really just a couple of steps:

(1) Create a user preference which is a BOOL called "runBefore". NSUserDefaults will return the default of NO, and you save "YES" whenever you save your preferences.

Then there are two cases, depending on whether you use a XIB for your first screen:

*If using an XIB:*

(2) In IB in that XIB, add a UIView overlaying your existing screen with the text/graphics to welcome your user and a big custom transparent button covering the whole view linked to a closeWelcome action.

(3) Then, in your first viewController in viewWillAppear, check for runBefore. If so, call your closeWelcome action, which removes it from its parent view

*OR if not currently using an XIB:*

(2) In IB, create an XIB with a UIView with the text/graphics to welcome your user and a big custom transparent button over the whole view linked to a closeWelcome action.

(3) Then, in your first viewController in viewWillAppear, check for runBefore. If not, put up the Welcome XIB.  Then the user will close it in your closeWelcome action, which removes it from the parent view.

Comment: I was looking for a framework because I was looking for something that would have more rigor than just a simple XIB overlay.  Stuff like perhaps new version tracking / indicating specific elements and even some interactivity.